# Using Parcel 2 with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parceljs

How can I output the javascript file from Parcel, include this javascript file in Rails `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`, and ideally get it working with hot module reloading?

Alternatively, is this a bad approach, and do you recommend something more streamlined, that lets me use mostly traditional .html.erb Rails templates but sprinkle in ReactJS UI components here and there?

I was able to do this perfectly in Parcel 1 but I am finding that the setup is quite different in Parcel 2.

I am using the traditional Rails 5 application.html.erb templating.

My attempt so far with Parcel 2 has been to use the [library](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/library/) tutorial in the Parcel documentation. I can mount the simplest React component to my Rails app but then if I try to import anything I get errors like `require is not defined`, and HMR is not working.

I'm not sure how much context to provide for this question. But if it helps, my previous setup with Parcel 1 was to have a separate npm app at the root folder (next to the Rails /app folder) which output a dist/index.js file using the npm script `parcel start app/index.jsx --out-dir dist --public-url /assets/dist`. This was added to the Rails assets via `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('frontend')` and included in app/assets/javascripts/application.js .

Now for Parcel 2 I removed the include in application.js and added `<script type="module" src="/assets/dist/index.js"></script>` in application.html.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors you're seeing that I might be able to help with:

1. Runtime errors like `require is not defined`. This would be expected if you set up parcel to output your javascript as a library target (as you indicated). Libraries are typically npm packages that are consumed by other projects. In this context, parcel will output a `commonjs` bundle (including `require`-based imports) that's intended to be processed by another bunder (maybe parcel again, or webpack) before it's ready to be executed in a browser. You probably want to build your javascript with a `browser` target instead, so that all dependencies are included without `require` statements to other packages.

   Assuming your `package.json` for the parcel project currently looks similar to the [the library tutorial](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/library/), the way you'd do that would be to remove the `"main": "path-to/my-root-javascript.js"` field, and change the `build` script to `parcel build path-to/my-root-javascript.js`. There's also a bunch of ways to customize this - see the [targets](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/library/) documentation.
2. HMR not working. If parcel is only in charge of bundling your javascript (and rails is building your html from templates), then the "normal" way that parcel does HMR won't work. This "normal" way would involve parcel injecting an HMR script in the `html` file that's its responsible for building and serving. But if Rails is taking care of the HTML, parcel can't do this automatically. Perhaps there is a way to configure rails to watch when parcel rebuilds the js bundle, and refresh the page?

This might be a bit of an onion-peeling exercise - it's hard to say if the above suggestions will solve it all end-to-end. If you can post a minimal reproduction of the issue (maybe a simplified version of your ruby + parcel project?) on github that shows the problem, I'm happy to troubleshoot it further.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your reply pointed my research to another answer you posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69532354/8749164 .  I am now able to use HMR seamlessly. Specifically this configuration worked: 

`"global": "dist/library.global.js",
  "targets": {
    "global": {
      "context": "browser",
      "outputFormat": "global"
    }
  },`